# Issue trying to het Kibana talking to Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, redhat, elastic-stack

I have Kibana and Elasticsearch on separate VMs.
Elasticsearch IP: 10.3.30.209
Kibana IP: 10.3.30.211

I am unable to curl the IP:PORT of Elasticsearch from Kibana:

```
curl 10.3.30.209:9200
curl: (7) Failed connect to 10.3.30.209:9200; Connection refused
```

The firewall on Elesticsearch server is listening for port 9200:

```
firewall-cmd --list-all
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: ens192
  sources:
  services: ssh dhcpv6-client
  ports: 9200/tcp
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

The Elasticsearch service was at least starting up before I modified the elasticsearch.yml file to enable listening on the elasticsearch port and bind the Kibana IP:

```
network.host: 10.3.30.211

# Set a custom port for HTTP:
#
# http.port: 9200
http.port: 9200
```

Error when starting service:

```
systemctl status elasticsearch
● elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2018-06-29 14:06:49 CDT; 1s ago

▽
     Docs: http://www.elastic.co
  Process: 6382 ExecStart=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -Des.pidfile=${PID_DIR}/elasticsearch.pid -Des.default.path.home=${ES_HOME} -Des.default.path.logs=${LOG_DIR} -Des.default.path.data=${DATA_DIR} -Des.default.path.conf=${CONF_DIR} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 6380 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-systemd-pre-exec (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 6382 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jun 29 14:06:49 elasticsearch01 elasticsearch[6382]: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
Jun 29 14:06:49 elasticsearch01 elasticsearch[6382]: at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Jun 29 14:06:49 elasticsearch01 elasticsearch[6382]: Refer to the log for complete error details.
Jun 29 14:06:49 elasticsearch01 elasticsearch[6382]: [2018-06-29 14:06:49,189][INFO ][node                     ] [Turac] stopping ...
Jun 29 14:06:49 elasticsearch01 elasticsearch[6382]: [2018-06-29 14:06:49,199][INFO ][node                     ] [Turac] stopped
Jun 29 14:06:49 elasticsearch01 elasticsearch[6382]: [2018-06-29 14:06:49,200][INFO ][node                     ] [Turac] closing ...
Jun 29 14:06:49 elasticsearch01 elasticsearch[6382]: [2018-06-29 14:06:49,204][INFO ][node                     ] [Turac] closed
Jun 29 14:06:49 elasticsearch01 systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 29 14:06:49 elasticsearch01 systemd[1]: Unit elasticsearch.service entered failed state.
Jun 29 14:06:49 elasticsearch01 systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service failed.
```

NOTE: I am able to ping the Elasticsearch server from Kibana.

Any help with figuring out why this change breaks the Elasticsearch service and how I might be able to connect my Kibana server to Elasticsearch would be appreciated!

Comment: it seems the IP address is different... you're trying to connect to 10.3.30.209 but the network.host points to 10.3.30.211, is it correct?

Comment: @s_bighead That fixed it, TY! I thought that I was supposed to be pointing it at Kibana which has the 211 IP